Congratulations, you're no longer in Beta!
This site started private beta before July 2012, so it is no longer "beta", it is a full site by our definition. We've removed the word "beta" from your site banner because we believe that you aren't really a beta site any more, even if you don't get ten questions per day.

What this means for you:

the "Beta" is removed from your banner
the site is moved to the "Launched" sites list on Area 51 - which will also remove the A51 info box from the right sidebar
retain beta reputation levels
full-site elections will be delayed but will be scheduled eventually

This is the start of a process that we are already discussing internally and will be bringing to the network for public discussion once the plan is finalized. My hope is that this will mean the end of the monolith we currently refer to as "Graduation" in favor of a well-defined set of small targets to achieve the various elements that made up "Graduation".
I'm sure you have many questions, please feel free to ask and I'll answer what I can. It helps me out a lot if you can limit answers to focus on a single question/subject rather than asking a dozen questions in one answer.
Please feel free to follow the MSE discussion for more background on this decision. You can ask questions either here or there; I'll try to keep up with all of them. Your mods also have some info, so they may be answering in my stead.
Thanks so much for your patience and stay tuned!

Awesome! 
Will we get our own custom banners, badges and what not?

Determining this will be part of the process we're working on that I describe. It takes us a really long time to create site designs and we already have many sites in queue, so even if we did add you to the list of sites waiting, it probably won't be any time soon. I am hoping that we can find a mid-term solution to give y'all something different from the beta theme, even if it's just a single full-site theme for all sites that aren't beta but don't have a custom design.

@Catija I don’t think we mind waiting, it’d just be nice to know it was on the way.

@Catija Can that be "outsourced" to contributors of Chinese Stackexchange? What design elements, other than the header, are needed?

Great!!
Will this site be getting a logo or not? I was hoping we can pick a logo from the question about this site getting a logo and what it will be.

It's the same story as the other design elements... that said, if you have a unicode symbol, we could use that instead of the "Cn". For example, before it got a site design, the Anime site's logo was the Kanji for anime. We could do something like that here. If that's interesting to y'all, open a meta discussion about it and decide which character you'd want.

There already is one here:the page

We can do just 漢 if that works but we can't make it decorative as the top answer there suggests.
